# Typescript map object type to strongly typed array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an object type which I want to map to a strongly typed key, value array.

This is what I came up with so far:

```js
export interface StepWidgetItem<T, V> {
    key: T;
    value: V;
}

interface UseStepWidgetsContainer<T extends object> {
    data: T;
}

interface UseStepWidgetsContainerProps<T extends object> {
    items: StepWidgetItem<keyof T, T[keyof T]>[];
}

export const useStepWidgetsContainer = <T extends object>({
    items,
}: UseStepWidgetsContainerProps<T>): UseStepWidgetsContainer<T> => {
    const data = {} as T;

    console.log(items);

    return {
        data,
    };
};
```

The problem i when I call it like this:

```js
interface Data {
    test: string;
    test2: number;
}

useStepWidgetsContainer<Data>({
    items: [
        {
            key: 'test',
            value: 'test',
        },
        {
            key: 'test2',
            value: 'test', // should be an error, but string is currently allowed...
        },
        {
            key: 'test2',
            value: 1,
        },
    ],
});
```

The value of array item with key: 'test2' must be a number, but currently it may be any type of the values of Data, so `string|number`.

Is it possible to force a number when key === 'test2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close The problem is that `StepWidgetItem<keyof T, T[keyof T]>` will mix any key of `T` with any value in `T`.

The solution is to first associate the key with the value  creating a type for each property, for ex: `StepWidgetItem<"test", string>` `StepWidgetItem<"test2", number>`. We can do this using a mapped type to first create for each property, the associated `StepWidgetItem` and then index into the mapped type using `[keyof T]` to get a union of all StepWidgetItem types we  just created.

```
interface UseStepWidgetsContainerProps<T extends object> {
    items: Array<{
      [P in keyof T]: StepWidgetItem<P, T[P]>
    }[keyof T]>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZVTAHUEATAc2BgElUBbAHgBUAaOANQD44BvAKDhC4Aa2ABPAFxxmAbkHCAbpgA2AV2DSO8gL79+yVBhx4AqgGdghYCXJUY5gMIQUmZGhZxQqJGXNwIACMAK2BsGB4BYTgyTBhMaTl+PQMUNCxcOAsrIlJKaicXePcoAAUoCDBzT29gX38g0PDIhSEEBnNpAEEoKExxRijouABtUsQkUQkIdBkAXWlrW3zaBkZS9mYxua5WuB0RsXEZ+d2U0EhYOGwXc3g1SyW8+0LXErgAXjgakB8-AJCYQiAAohm0OqxktJsk87AVnG8kGhypVqswuABKaGPXJwhwI4pIqAsHgfFrRG5IO4xOKYT58HRwTD+JJ7SnmCAqYAAOhUEAowPawHo5gx8j2UGoaigkzBw1i8Uh0R0unkhnSJjgABFaXw9qg7tI7lBkBR5NEDTAAEzSJBqeiBNC6fQPHI2Z7wopuImMHXxLigvZCkXSEZ7aJy4bCI7SADkltjSqjw2U6k0cHjwDuifDwh0SajkeTMYzlqtOeTKdUGjjCfYAHp63BzAALCBqFRkOCOpmTNAVKDsQJqeDG02IfzYaWSlAqcRMlR8gDuwDI3PXuaE+c3esr0RLmbu5YLe9TNbgAEYT8qT3NIToxUA)

Comment: This method has a problem, a complicated-looking type error appears when I use it in my case, Similar to what you'll see if you open the Playground Link